# ESTA still valid but new passport. can I ask for a new esta?

Tags: passports, esta

I'm an italian citizen, with a still valid ESTA. Anyway in the meantime I got a new passport, so I will have to ask for a new ESTA.
Before doing anything wrong, I would like to know if I should do something with the old ESTA (like communicate to the embassy that it should be canceled) or I simply start a new ESTA request procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just apply for a new ESTA

From the [ESTA FAQ](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/faq?lang=en) :

> Each Visa Waiver Program traveler must have an approved travel authorization for the passport they plan to use before they travel to the United States. If a traveler obtains a new passport, they must submit a new travel authorization application in ESTA using the **new** passport. A processing fee will be charged for each new application submitted.

Comment: my only doubt was what to do with the old esta. but that answer is clear, thanks